# Reactjs - am I obligated to pass my nested components in a div box to trigger a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with ReactJS. I have a nested component as follow :

my componentParent.js :

```
import ComponentA {...}
 <div {some properties}> 
            <div 
              {some properties}>
            </div> 
            <ComponentA/>   
 </div>
```

my componentA.js :

```
import ComponentB {...}
 foo.map{..} return (
 <div onClick={this.onClick}> 
              <ComponentB/>
</div>)
```

on the componentA.js if I display directly the Component B and place the onClick method inside as :

```
import ComponentB {...}
 foo.map{..} return (
              <ComponentB onClick={this.onClick}/>
)
```

The method refuses to trigger on ComponentB in the second case. Am I always obligated to nest my component in a Div in order to trigger a function or existing a way to `onClick` directly on componentB ? 
Any hint would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass 'onClick' to a component, it's a prop. When you assign it to plain old HTML element ("POHE"), React converts it to an event handler. Somewhere you need to assign it to an "POHE"

With your second version of `ComponentA`:

```
import ComponentB {...}
 foo.map{..} return <ComponentB onClick={this.onClick}/>
```

If you modify `<ComponentB>` to call `onClick={this.props.onClick}` on a div or something, you'll see this is so.

Here's [a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/269611/):

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

function blah() {
  console.log('sdfsdf');
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" onClick={blah}/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: hmmmm... thanks, so the question is : how make the element past on the component an event handler I guess and if possible of course

Comment: @Webman Where the actual `onClick` is defined? And in which component you want to call it?

Comment: Currently the onClick function is defined in the state area above the render function, in the same component. I pass it in a div and is works great. I would just know if that was possible to make the game play differently